# Using libvlc on android with NDK

Tags: c, sockets, android-ndk, libvlc

I am currently messing around a bit with libvlc on android using the NDK.
Well, I understand how to use native C code in an android app.
Now I would like to use the libvlc library to make a simple player which would read data from a socket.

Is it possible to use libvlc at that level? The problem I see is when it comes to set a window handler for libvlc to draw the image on.

Has anyone experienced with this that could give me some feedback?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be interested in this - https://bitbucket.org/tewilove/nyan.tv-jni/src

Edit: Looks like the nyan.tv link doesn't exist anymore. A possibly more 'official' sample is here -> https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample

Comment: Thanks for the link! Sorry for taking some time responding but I had some other projects that took priority and I almost forgot this one :)