# Using the vlclib on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, udp, vlc, rtsp

Well i´m trying to create a application which should show some streams (udp/rtsp..) I found out that the vlc-player can handle most of it! So i decided to use the vlclib. On windows there is a vlclib which can be easily used. But how can i use the vlc-android project as a vlclib for my own app?

On the web i found another question:
[Using libvlc on android with NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893578/using-libvlc-on-android-with-ndk)

The answer links to this side:
https://bitbucket.org/tewilove/nyan.tv-jni/src

But the readme is really strange. It tells me only to compile it using the shell script... But this side referring to the nyan.tv-jni project tells me that i can use it simply as a wrapper in my code? http://blog.moenyan.net/?p=18

So now i´m really confused... Can anyone please help me shed some light on how to create my own app using the lib?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. I decided to build my application into the vlc application. I cloned the git-project from vlc and followed the instruction to build a ARM-CPU version. After the successful compilation I was able to merge my project into the vlc application.

Just change the package in the AndroidManifest.xml, change the declared classes from for example:

```
.GUI.Main to org.videolan.GUI.Main
```

Remember to do not register your Main as the starting activity. Just start your activity after finishing the onCreate() of the VLC-Main activity. Remember to call finish() in the onResume() of the VLC-Main activity. The onResume() will be called after your destroyed your own activity.

```
// OnCreate
VLC.Main.onCreate() -> startActivity(Intent) -> MyApplication.Main.onCreate()
// OnDestroy
MyApplication.Main.onDestroy() -> VLC.Main.onResume() -> VLC.Main.onDestroy()
```

/!\ Remember to credit the VLC-Team for the great base!

Comment: hi 
can you please tell me how did you build vlc for android